# Error in EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86 package to convert ensembl to symbol

Tags: r, runtime-error, bioconductor, install.packages, biomart

I installed package EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86 to convert genes ensembl to symbol,
after trying many packages that's the best one to conversion with less NAs.
I tried to write the code but I got unsual error, here's my code:

```
library(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86)
mapIds = mapIds (EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86,
             keys = genes, 
             keytype = "GENEID", 
             column = "SYMBOL")
```

after that code conversion must be done, but I got this error:

> Error: 'filter' has to be an 'AnnotationFilter', a list of 'AnnotationFilter' object, an 'AnnotationFilterList' or a valid filter expression!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your keys are problematic, e.g. not a character vector. Try if it works for you with the reproducible example below:

```r
library(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86)
genes <- c("ENSG00000102145", "ENSG00000179348", "ENSG00000107485")
mapIds(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86,
             keys = genes, 
             keytype = "GENEID", 
             column = "SYMBOL")
#> ENSG00000102145 ENSG00000179348 ENSG00000107485 
#>         "GATA1"         "GATA2"         "GATA3"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: YES THAT'S RIGHT.. so I just convert it to vector with this code: `genes <- as.vector(genes[,1])`